# Complex number, series representation

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

Show that for any finite value of $z$
$$e^z=e+e\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}$$

For $z=1$
$$f(z)=f(z_0)+\sum f^{(n)}(z_0)\frac{(z-z_0)^n}{n!}$$

equality is checked, but I do not know how to show for any finite value of z, I tried to apply the principle of induction but not worked well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **radius of convergence** of the following power series
$$
e^{z-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-1)^n}{n!} \tag1
$$ is **infinite**, as may be seen by the ratio test for example.

Thus $(1)$ is valid for any finite complex value of $z$, and you get your identity by writing
$$
e^{z}=e\:e^{z-1} \tag2
$$ and using $(1)$.